# Google Chrome Inspect Element in .NET

Tags: html, .net, google-chrome, hook

Is it possible for one to hook onto / access and edit a webpage's contents (like in the inspect element feature) live in chrome using .NET? Can this be done discreetly in the background as well. I don't have any malicious intentions, just creating a simple hack for a game online that relies on its HTML sourcing.

Comment: Chrome has a JSON api via [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol).

Comment: Try writing a TamperMonkey script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a headless browser like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to do this, they provide an easy .NET library that allows you to interact with a browser programmatically. Also, points for being aware that the question sounds suspicious.

Comment: I guess I COULD use Selenium and their library. But that would mean that if I planned to release the hack, then every user who wants to use it would need Selenium right? I specifically asked for Chrome for the reason that it's the main browser within my school(where I plan to release the hack to the my peers).